# MOV vs MOV.B assembly language instruction

Tags: assembly

I'm working through the Microcorruption CTF which uses an emulated MSP430 CPU.

I've seen several mov instruction examples like:

`mov sp, r4 ; move value of stack pointer to register 4`

`mov #0xfffc, r15 ; move hex value fffc to r15`

I'm trying to interpret:

`mov.b  #0x4f, 0x0(r15)`

I assume mov.b is binary value of #0x4f, but I'm not sure what `0x0(r15)` indicates.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means use a byte operation:

```
The suffix .B at the instruction memonic will result in a byte operation
```

So only a byte of data will be copied from the source to the destination.

0x0(r15) is an indexed addressing mode, so use r15 + 0 bytes to specify the destination.

Comment: Thanks...why all the ceremony with mov.b instead of mov #0x04f, r15 ?

Comment: Because what you wrote moves the value into r15. What's in the code moves it into the byte pointed to by r15.

Comment: Yes - it allows you to modify a portion of the data in the register specified, and at any byte position within the register.