# Assembly language: What are the main differences between byte operations and word operations?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

In the process of practicing reverse-engineering with [microcorruption](https://microcorruption.com), I came across instructions like `mov.b` `cmp.b`. I looked it up online and I found out they're called "byte operations". There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533375/mov-vs-mov-b-assembly-language-instruction) on stack overflow about the differences between `mov` and `mov.b`, but unfortunately, I couldn't really understand the answer.

So, my question is "What are the main differences between byte operations and word operations?", particularly what's the difference between `mov.b` and `mov`, or `cmp` and `cmp.b`. Thank you very much.

Comment: "word operations" does not help you.  An Intel processor has distinct MOV and CMP instructions that take 1 byte, 2 byte, 4 byte or 8 byte operands.  Respectively b, w, l and q in AT&T assembly syntax.  The postfix can be omitted if the data size is obvious from the operands, register moves for example.

Answer (score 2):

A byte operation operates on a single byte, a word operation operates on a word of data.  Typical *word sizes* are 2, 4, or 8 bytes, that is 16 bits, 32 bits, or 64 bits.

Assuming a word size of 16 bits, for example, if you write the byte `0x23` to memory location `0x1000`, then the value of the memory at address `0x1000` is changed to `0x23`.  If you write the word `0x2342` to address `0x1000`, then the effect depends on your machine's *endianess.*  On a *little endian* machine where the least significant byte is stored first, the memory at address `0x1000` receives the value `0x42` and the memory at address `0x1001` receives the value `0x23`.  On *big endian* machines, it's the other way round.

The same applies to all other instructions.

Many modern processors only have arithmetic instructions for word sized data with the only byte-sized instructions being special load and store instructions.  In such architectures, the data in a single byte is zero-extended or sign-extended to a full word when being loaded into a register so you can operate on it like on a full word.  For example, `0x80` becomes `0x0080` when zero-extended and `0xff80` when sign-extended.

Answer (score 1):

The suffix of operation in `mov` and`cmp` indicates the size that will be modified in operation. Example: `mov $ 2, (% ebx)`. Will the number 2 be moved to 1 byte of ebx or will the number 2 be moved to 4 bytes in ebx? The size prefixes `b`, `w`, and `l` serve this purpose, indicating sizes of 1, 2, and 4 bytes respectively. For more: http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs421/papers/x86-asm/asm.html

Comment: This isn't an x86 question (AT&T syntax doesn't use `cmp.b`, it would be `cmpb`, but yeah it's similar.  (The space between the `%` and the `ebx` is valid though.  You have to write `%ebx`.  `$ 2` might be valid, if weird.)